# Issue when rendering a new state in React

Tags: reactjs

I am still new in react, and i am having trouble to figure it out how to fix an issue with the useState method when i call a function, i try to simplifie as much as possible the code in below as example (on the front-end) :

```
function App() {
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("")
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
                                      id: '',
                                      name: '',
                                      email: '',
                                      entries: '',
                                    })
    const loadUser = (data) => {
       setUser({
          id: data.id,
          name: data.name,
          email: data.email,
          entries: data.entries,
        })
    } 
    const onPictureSubmit = () => {
      setImageUrl(input)
      // running some random App
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          fetch('server URL/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body:JSON.stringify({
              id: user.id
            })
          })
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          // the issue is from the code below
          .then(count => {
            setUser(Object.assign(user, {entries: count}))        
          })  
      }
      })    
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    return (
      <>
        <div>
            <Rank data= {user}/>
          // information is loaded from the Signin component
          and then update the user State.
            <Signin loadUser= {loadUser}/>
          // onPictureSubmit is called from ImageLink component
            <ImageLink handleSumit={onPictureSubmit}/>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  export default App;
```

Code on the Rank component to show how the user.entries is rendering :

```
const Rank =({data}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div >
               {`${data.name}, your current entry count is...`} 
            </div>
            <div >
               {`${data.entries}`} 
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Rank;
```

code on the back-end server where the request is fetch from :

```
app.put('/image', (req, resp) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if (user.id === id) {
            found = true
            user.entries++
            resp.json(user.entries);
        } 
    })
    if (!found) {
       resp.status(404).json('no such user') 
    }   
})
```

**what i expect this code to do :**
when onPictureSubmit is called, the data.entries is updated from the state with the count, and the number is updated on the rendering each time "onPictureSubmit" function is triggered.

**what the code really do :**
when onPictureSubmit trigger the first time, the rendering from data.entries is not updated immediatly, only the second time and so on the rendering is updated. (I think the reason is the fact useState method is also asynchronous)

Comment: Where is `onPictureSubmit` called? And what is the role of `loadUser`?

Comment: onPictureSubmit is called from an onClick function from another component, I didn't showed in the code before,  and  loadUser receive information from the Signin component and then update the information on the user State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to fix it myself, looks like the issue is with the `Object.assign` method which didn't work as expected even though I still don't understand why... however when I replaced it with the entire Object like below :

```
const onPictureSubmit = () => {
      setImageUrl(input)
      // running some random App
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          fetch('server URL/image', {
            method: 'put',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body:JSON.stringify({
              id: user.id
            })
          })
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          // replacing the method below by the prev object
          .then(count => {
             setUser(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                entries: count
             }))
          })
```

Now it works. The entry count rendering is now updated whenever `onPictureSubmit` is triggered.
Update : better way to update the entry count state.